Can I ask for the first reviewer's comments while I wait for the second?
I submitted a manuscript to a journal seven months ago, and I recently received an update stating that one review has been returned while another is still pending. The editorial office mentioned they will arrive at a decision as soon as possible.
Given the lengthy review process, is it appropriate for me to ask for the comments from the first reviewer? I would like to understand their feedback to help me decide whether to withdraw my manuscript or continue with the process.

Why would you withdraw your manuscript based on the first report?

if the comment is negative, the possibility of rejection becomes significantly higher and it may not be worth waiting for a response from the journal.

But you have already waited seven months, which presumably means you will have to wait significantly less time to get a final decision than if you withdraw and resubmit to a different journal. And the second report may be positive. Frankly I don’t see the logic of withdrawing part way through the process based on incomplete information on what one referee thinks, unless you yourself have lost faith in your own work.

Yes, you can ask, but I wouldn't mention the possibility of withdrawing when you do. They might comply or not, but given it has been a while, I'd guess they might be fine with it.
Focus the letter on the fact that you may need to think about improvements as needed.
